# How can use sqlContext in spark udf

Tags: pyspark, user-defined-functions

I'm trying to load a json file in spark UDF and use it to query something. What i need to do is to do use a column value (storeId) from a data frame and  use it in

But, i get a pickle error. If I try coding without the sqlContext then it work.

Is there any workaround or is this not possible.

```
def get_id_udf (storeId,sqlContext):

   df = sqlContext.read.json("file_url_s3")

   if storeId == None:
       return None

   return None

from pyspark.sql.functions import udf, col

from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType

desc_udf = udf(lambda storeId : get_id_udf(storeId,sqlContext),       IntegerType())
```

> ```
> ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
> TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
> <ipython-input-22-b5c4070c110e> in <module>()
>       1 from pyspark.sql.functions import udf, col
>       2 from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType
> ----> 3 desc_udf = udf(lambda storeId : get_cluster_id_udf(storeId,sqlContext), IntegerType())
>
> /usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/functions.py in udf(f, returnType)
>    1799     [Row(slen=5), Row(slen=3)]
>    1800     """
> -> 1801     return UserDefinedFunction(f, returnType)
>    1802 
>    1803 blacklist = ['map', 'since', 'ignore_unicode_prefix']
>
> /usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/functions.py in __init__(self, func, returnType, name)
>    1758         self.returnType = returnType
>    1759         self._broadcast = None
> -> 1760         self._judf = self._create_judf(name)
>    1761 
>    1762     def _create_judf(self, name):
>
> /usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/functions.py in _create_judf(self, name)
>    1763         from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
>    1764         sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate()
> -> 1765         wrapped_func = _wrap_function(sc, self.func, self.returnType)
>    1766         ctx = SQLContext.getOrCreate(sc)
>    1767         jdt = ctx._ssql_ctx.parseDataType(self.returnType.json())
>
> /usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/functions.py in _wrap_function(sc, func, returnType)
>    1743 def _wrap_function(sc, func, returnType):
>    1744     command = (func, returnType)
> -> 1745     pickled_command, broadcast_vars, env, includes = _prepare_for_python_RDD(sc, command)
>    1746     return sc._jvm.PythonFunction(bytearray(pickled_command), env, includes,
> ```
>
> sc.pythonExec,
>          1747                                   sc.pythonVer, broadcast_vars, sc._javaAccumulator)
>
> ```
> /usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/rdd.py in _prepare_for_python_RDD(sc, command)
>    2313     # the serialized command will be compressed by broadcast
>    2314     ser = CloudPickleSerializer()
> -> 2315     pickled_command = ser.dumps(command)
>    2316     if len(pickled_command) > (1 << 20):  # 1M
>    2317         # The broadcast will have same life cycle as created PythonRDD
>
> /usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/serializers.py in dumps(self, obj)
>     426 
>     427     def dumps(self, obj):
> --> 428         return cloudpickle.dumps(obj, 2)
>     429 
>     430 
>
> /usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/cloudpickle.py in dumps(obj, protocol)
>     655 
>     656     cp = CloudPickler(file,protocol)
> --> 657     cp.dump(obj)
>     658 
>     659     return file.getvalue()
>
> /usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/cloudpickle.py in dump(self, obj)
>     105         self.inject_addons()
>     106         try:
> --> 107             return Pickler.dump(self, obj)
>     108         except RuntimeError as e:
>     109             if 'recursion' in e.args[0]:
>
> /usr/lib64/python2.7/pickle.pyc in dump(self, obj)
>     222         if self.proto >= 2:
>     223             self.write(PROTO + chr(self.proto))
> --> 224         self.save(obj)
>     225         self.write(STOP)
>     226 
>
>
> /usr/lib64/python2.7/pickle.pyc in save(self, obj)
>     284         f = self.dispatch.get(t)
>     285         if f:
> --> 286             f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
>     287             return
>     288 
>
> /usr/lib64/python2.7/pickle.pyc in save_dict(self, obj)
>     653 
>     654         self.memoize(obj)
> --> 655         self._batch_setitems(obj.iteritems())
>     656 
>     657     dispatch[DictionaryType] = save_dict
>
> /usr/lib64/python2.7/pickle.pyc in _batch_setitems(self, items)
>     685                 for k, v in tmp:
>     686                     save(k)
> --> 687                     save(v)
>     688                 write(SETITEMS)
>     689             elif n:
>
> /usr/lib64/python2.7/pickle.pyc in save(self, obj)
>     304             reduce = getattr(obj, "__reduce_ex__", None)
>     305             if reduce:
> --> 306                 rv = reduce(self.proto)
>     307             else:
>     308                 reduce = getattr(obj, "__reduce__", None)
>
> TypeError: 'JavaPackage' object is not callable
> ```

Comment: You cannot use a spark context inside a `UDF` (on every worker), you can only call it from the driver. What do you want to do with this json file?

Comment: I was trying to read the json file using sqlContext.read.json() and use sqlContext.sql(..) to query stuff from it. But, I did find a work around where I flattened the jsonfile into an array and loop to do my query. Seems that this will be inefficient. So, I really wanted to see if there is a spark way to do this. But, from you comments it looks like UDF needs to be on every worker and hence cannot have spark stuff. Is that right.

Comment: Why do you need to load the same file as many times are there are rows in your dataframe?

Comment: I thought about that. I think I'll stick to read the data in an array/map at the driver and pass the map  to the udf. I think that is the only way this will work better